Help identifying "A32F" and "G9" chips used in USB-C cable built in wattmeters
I have been trying to identify the chips that are used in "power meter" USB C cables and adapters. I have purchased and taken apart the following two adapters for this:
Adapter 1 - No name 100W
Adapter 2 - Essager 240W
Outside photos:


Looking inside them, it can be seen that one chip handles the power reading, calculation, and driving the LED 7-segment displays which are charlieplexed/multiplexed, and another chip is present, which I was able to identify on the 100W adapter as a linear regulator, with the other adapter presumably using a fully integrated buck converter chip as it has to handle a conversion from 48V (PN OCQ or 0CQ, 6 pin 2x2 package). The chip on the 100W adapter reads "G9", while the chip on the 240W adapter reads "A32F  02".
Both chips appear to be QFN-16 3x3 packages. I have been trying to find these chips for two days, including using tools such as https://smd.yooneed.one/ but was not able to find them. I like the fact that one tiny chip handles both the power reading and 7 segment display. The chips do not have access to the CC or D+/D- lines and only infer PD communication for the "PD" light by the Vbus voltage (this might just be using an internal comparator and voltage divider. I assume these chips are not related to USB, but I have not seen them used in other applications)
Inside photos:

In this photo, the LED side is shown flipped to match the via locations, this PCB appears to be 4+ layers.


Here is the 7 segment display from the 100W adapter, it itself is a module with only 5/6 pads connected (driving 18 LEDs), which makes it obvious that the 7 segment display is charlieplexed, and this was confirmed by filming a high FPS video in which it was seen that the LEDs take turns to be on.

Can someone please help find these chips? Thank you!

A32F is probably a 32-bit ARM or RISC-V MCU from a Chinese semiconductor manufacturer. Program loaded through the USB port.

While this is plausible, I looked deeper on that adapter (the 240W one) and was not able to find a connection between the chip and any pins on either USB connector. 4 pins connect to gnd/shunts, 1 to Vcc, 1 to a voltage divider from Vbus to gnd, 7 to LEDs, and the remaining 3 pins seemed to be NC. I could be missing something and an MCU makes sense, however I think it might be "pre-programmed" for this task, or an ASIC
